# the dress of the followers of Harav Kook

Tags: history, clothing, abraham-isaac-kook

Harav Kook was basically a litai, and dressed like one and even had a shtreimel.
Today his followers and talmidim from his yeshiva don't even use any kind of suit (long or short) or hat and even make a point dressing like this (with the typical kipa sruga).

In general the tsiburim dress like the rav they follow, so my question is why when and how this change happened.

Comment: Maybe consider reformulating this question to something like: How do Jewish religious groups decide on a dress code? And, why do different groups follow different codes? And, why are there groups that seem to have no code at all?

Comment: Please rephrase to exclude implied value judgements (e.g. "claim to be"), or we'll have to close this.

Comment: There is a picture of the current R"Y of Mercaz HaRav here:http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/יעקב_אלעזר_כהנא_שפירא and he seems to fit the description of 'classical attire' so I'm not entirely sure what the question is even based on, unless you mean the children.

Comment: I mean the tsibur in general, apparently the rosh yeshiva is more careful with this, but not all rabanim are like this.

Comment: Fixing the link posted by @Curiouser: [WP](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90)

Comment: +1 because I also find it interesting that many of his _admirers_ and readers of his work don't dress like he did. But are they part of his "tsibur"? Even if you say yes, what makes you think that, "In general the tsiburim dress like the rav they follow?" In _Hassidic_ circles this is certainly true. But outside of that, it is more of a _norm_ than a _uniform_. Norms can change over time. Granted, the "black hat" _norm_ seems to have stuck around for a long time at this point, but here and there you can see some changes even to that.

Answer (score 6):

> In general the tsiburim dress like the rav they follow.

I think this premise of your question is mistaken. From what I've heard, dressing like the rav is a practice that the Chassidim introduced and that only spread to other groups relatively recently. In particular, the Lithuanian tradition, until at most a generation or so ago, included much less uniform dress.

Comment: well, today the kipa sruga tsibur dresses pretty much in uniform, the talmidim and rabanim

Comment: @Avraham That's much more likely due to the natural forces of style than to minhag or explicit rav-emulation.

Comment: so you mean the change happened because his talmidim decided to follow a style while other groups of Lithuanian emulated the hasidim?

Comment: @Avraham I mean that everyone always follows style, with the occasional exception of groups that explicitly take on a particular minhag or emulate the dress of a particular leader. Yeshivish people who dress uniformly are somewhere in between, since they're following the style of the people around them, and many of them consider elements of their dress to be a minhag.

Comment: this is the point of my question, at some point the talmidim of mercav harav started following a different dress style than other Lithuanian yeshivot

Comment: @Avraham This is the point of my answer: There was *no such thing* as an official dress style in Lithuanian yeshivot until relatively recently, when many of them started dressing uniformly like chassidim.

Comment: sorry on being persistent, I'm really trying to understand. So you are saying that at some point some litaim went this way and some that way? in any case what do you mean by recently?

Comment: @Avraham Yes. Regarding timing, [R' Rakeffet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Rakeffet-Rothkoff) has spoken about how in his youth in 1940s US, the litvish yeshiva people were not dressing uniformly, so the widespread adoption of uniform dress was more recent than that.

Comment: I can back up @Isaac on this: I heard from my Rosh Yeshiva (R' A.C. Goldfein ZT"L) that in Telz, R' Elya Meir Bloch ZT"L used to wear a white hat, and his beard was a close-cropped goatee.  The whole concept of a uniform dress code is completely non-Litvish.

Comment: well, even if not uniform apparently they did use some hat and suit

Answer (score 4):

Amongst the Religious-Zionist community, like perhaps all communitites, students generally follow the intellectual perspective of their Rav.

In my yeshiva, [Yeshivat Har Etzion](http://www.haretzion.org/), Rav Lichtenstein (Rosh Yeshiva) wears a suit as do rabbanim who made aliya from America. Israeli rabbanim and students are more likely to wear coloured trousers/shirts and any type of shoes or sandals.

Although the actual dress varies, the thinking behind the choice is similar. Each individual wears what they feel to be respectable clothing, befitting a ben torah.

A difference between more Charedi communities and more "modern" ones is that Charedi communities receive specific guidance from their leaders on the minutae of everyday life (Daas Torah), ranging from dress code to permissable cellphone model (Badatz give hechsherim to phones) . In the Dati Leumi world people are expected to make their own informed decisions and not rely on the example of their leaders for minor decisions.

Answer (score 3):

The Kohain Godol dressed differently than the masses. You see amongst Chasidim often the Rebbe wears a different Bekeshe or Gartel than the masses. You see amongst the Litfeshe that often the Rosh haYeshiva wears a Frock or something different than the masses. And you see amongst the followers of HaRav Kook that they wear different clothing than HaRav Kook.